# Group by multiple fields and output tuple

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a feed in the following format:

```
Hour Key  ID  Value
   1  K1 001      3
   1  K1 002      2
   2  K1 005      4
   1  K2 002      1
   2  K2 003      5
   2  K2 004      6
```

and I want to group the feed by `(Hour, Key)` then sum the `Value` but keep `ID` as a tuple:

```
({1, K1}, {001, 002}, 5)
({2, K1}, {005}, 4)
({1, K2}, {002}, 1)
({2, K2}, {003, 004}, 11)
```

I know how to use `FLATTEN` to generate the sum of the `Value` but don't know how to output `ID` as a tuple. This is what I have so far:

```
A = LOAD 'data' AS (Hour:chararray, Key:chararray, ID:chararray, Value:int);
B = GROUP A BY (Hour, Key);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE
    FLATTEN(group) AS (Hour, Key),
    SUM(A.Value) AS Value
;
```

Will you explain how to do this? Appreciate it!

Comment: Can you provide the final state / output you are looking for - not sure i understand what you mean by "output ID as a tuple"

Comment: @Chris, the final state would be somehow like the piece I have above: `(Hour, Key)` as the key, all its associated `ID(s)` as in a tuple (like `{001, 002}`, etc.) plus the sum of `Value`. Please let me know if it makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just need to use the bag projection operator, `.`.  This will create a new bag where the tuples have just the element(s) you specify.  In your case, use `A.ID`.  In fact, you are already using this operator to provide the input to `SUM` -- the input to sum is a bag of single-element tuples, which you create by projecting the `Value` field.

```
A = LOAD 'data' AS (Hour:chararray, Key:chararray, ID:chararray, Value:int);
B = GROUP A BY (Hour, Key);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE
    FLATTEN(group) AS (Hour, Key),
    A.ID,
    SUM(A.Value) AS Value
;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Winnie. This is great. Guess I still need a better grasp how bag works in Pig. Thanks!